# How to use libs-for-android Library?

Tags: android

Can any one guide me on how to use this library in Android?
I didn't find any tutorial or example related to this library.

I want to use an `ImageView` with a remote image while loading with progress spinner.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the getting started guide on the project homepage?
http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/wiki/GettingStarted

It seems to contain instructions on adding the libraries to your project, and also build in the example applications. And of course the example applications contain their full source so it shows you how to use the libs in an application.